# Using the beta polynomial, how can I get a weighting scheme that gives the full weight to the first lag and zeros to all other lags?

Tags: r, time-series, beta

Using the normalized beta polynomial, how can I get a weighting scheme that gives the full weight to the first lag and zeros to all other lags?

Here is the formula

```
nbeta   <- function(p,d)  {
eps   <- .Machine$double.eps
xi    <- (1:d - 1)/(d - 1)
xi[1] <- xi[1]+eps
xi[d] <- xi[d]-eps
nb    <- xi^(p[2] - 1) * (1 - xi)^(p[3] - 1)
w     <- p[1]*(nb/sum(nb)) }
```

NB: nbeta(p = c(1, 0, 1), d = 68) gives numerical but not exact solution, I want the first lag to have the full weight and all other lags get zeros.
Thanks guys

Comment: I think this would be more suited for `Cross Validation` https://stats.stackexchange.com/ I also think there is a package out there to solve this without having to code the statistical functions yourself.